# Deleting focused entry widget on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I added a feature to my program where upon adding an image, the path of the image will be displayed in an entry widget. Now I would like to add the possibility to delete these path entries. When clicking on an entry, it should take focus. A button click should then delete the entry currently in focus. The below code seems to fail at the 'Entry Widget Focus' part as the focus always stays on the 'txtImage1' entry. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#Variables

Image1 = StringVar()
Image2 = StringVar()
Image3 = StringVar()
Image4 = StringVar()

#Image Path Entry Widgets

lblImage1 = Label(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), text="Image 1", bg="#d9e1f1")
lblImage1.grid(row=2,column=0)
txtImage1 = Entry(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), textvariable=Image1, bg="ghost white", width = 10)
txtImage1.grid(row=3,column=0)

lblImage2 = Label(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), text="Image 2", bg="#d9e1f1")
lblImage2.grid(row=2,column=1)
txtImage2 = Entry(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), textvariable=Image2, bg="ghost white", width = 10)
txtImage2.grid(row=3,column=1)

lblImage3 = Label(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), text="Image 3", bg="#d9e1f1")
lblImage3.grid(row=2,column=2)
txtImage3 = Entry(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), textvariable=Image3, bg="ghost white", width = 10)
txtImage3.grid(row=3,column=2)

lblImage4 = Label(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), text="Image 4", bg="#d9e1f1")
lblImage4.grid(row=2,column=3)
txtImage4 = Entry(PictureFrame2, font=('Arial',12), textvariable=Image4, bg="ghost white", width = 10)
txtImage4.grid(row=3,column=3)

#Entry Widget Focus

def image1click(event):
    txtImage1.focus_set()
txtImage1.bind("<Button-1>", image1click)

def image2click(event):
    txtImage2.focus_set()
txtImage2.bind("<Button-1>", image2click)

def image3click(event):
    txtImage3.focus_set()
txtImage3.bind("<Button-1>", image3click)

def image4click(event):
    txtImage4.focus_set()
txtImage4.bind("<Button-1>", image4click)


#Delete Image on Focus

def Deleteimage():
    messageDelete= tkinter.messagebox.askyesno ("","Do you want to delete this image?")
    if messageDelete > 0:
        try:
            if txtImage1.focus_get():
                Image1.set("")
            else:
                if txtImage2.focus_get():
                    Image2.set("")
                else:
                    if txtImage3.focus_get():
                        Image3.set("")
                    else:
                        if txtImage4.focus_get():
                            Image4.set("") 
        except Exception:
            pass

#Delete Button

btnDeleteImage = Button(PictureFrame, text='Delete', font=('arial',12), height=1, width=12, bd=2, padx=13, command=Deleteimage)
btnDeleteImage.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`focus_get()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns the actual widget that has focus. `txtImage1.focus_get()`, `txtImage2.focus_get()`, etc all will return the same thing: the widget that has focus.

You can replace that whole if/else chain with this (and you can use any widget in place of `txtImage1`):

```
widget = txtImage1.focus_get()
widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Also, there's no need to call a function on a button click to set the focus, that happens automatically.

Comment: This solved the problem, and saved quite some code, thank you so much!